# Определить уровень RSSI в WEB

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript, php, wifi

Есть ли способы определить уровень сигнала RSSI Wi-Fi точки в WEB? Например с помощью JavaScript.

Нужно, чтобы при заходе на web-страницу с мобильного устройства отображался уровень сигнала RSSI до той WI-FI точки, к которой подключено это мобильное устройство.

Топология:
[image]

**UPD: (08.07.2015)**

Вот чего смог добиться!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: черз браузер нет (если не расширение) на ноде -да.

Comment: @eicto, т.е. на node.js можно?

Comment: @eicto необходим доступ к нативным методам/устройствам телефона. Нода это может/умеет, но нужно будет поискать библиотеку для этого, тут ведь еще зависит от платформы ( android/iOS ). Расширение, кстати, скорее все тоже не вариант, ибо оно не умеет копаться во внутренностях телефона ( иначе нарушение безопасности и все такое )
P.S. Прикол еще в том, что нода должна быть на телефоне)

Comment: Пока нашел одно решение: web-сервер определяет mac пользователя и по этому mac адресу, через telnet делает запрос на роутер и вытаскивает этот RSSI. Но этот запрос очень долгий, примерно секунд 5-7,а нужно не более 1 секунды.

Comment: Наверное я отстал от жизни раз на JavaScript можно определить уровень сигнала wi-fi :)

Comment: У вас ограниченный набор пользователей, роутер или какое-то определенное помещение, или показывать нужно абсолютно всем в интернете RSSI до его роутера?

Comment: @lsillarionov только тем, кто подключен к этой Wi-Fi точке.

Comment: **UPD: (08.07.2015)**

Вот чего смог добиться - http://i.stack.imgur.com/Npvp1.jpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вы никак не сможете узнать исключительно через JavaScript RSSI/SNR учтенный собственно клиентским устройством - стандартных методов для этого разработчиками браузеров не предусмотренно.

Однако вы можете показывать клиенту его же RSSI/SNR, учтенные самой точкой доступа, если она поддерживает мониторинг этих данных каким-либо образом.. Многие Cisco и Mikrotik'и умеют выдавать их посредством SNMP. Про точки доступа других фирм я не знаю.

Достаточно поднять веб-сервер, и на нем развернуть небольшое веб-приложение, которое будет опрашивать точку к которой подключен клиент, выбирать данные по конкретно этому клиенту, и отдавать их обратно клиенту в виде JSON-ответа, например. Ну а дальше - обращатся с клиента к этому веб-серверу через AJAX, и отображать полученные значения где необходимо.

Если для авторизации используется RADIUS, то информацию о клиенте и точке доступа к которой он подключен можно вытащить c RADIUS-сервера.

Если же авторизация не используется, либо используется WEP/WPA/WPA2, то для получения информации о клиенте и точке доступа, вы можете использовать клиентский IP и MAC - если веб-сервер и точки доступа находятся в пределах одной сети на коммутаторах, то MAC-адрес полученный веб-сервером всегда будет идентифицировать точку доступа к которой клиент подключен, а IP - непосредственно клиента на ней.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй копнуть сюда:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/connection

Хотя не разбирался.

Comment: 1. Это очень экспериментальный API
2. Информации о уровне сигнала он не предоставляет